# Howto unlink my google accounts from someone else's computer

Tags: gmail, google-account

On SOMEONE ELSE'S computer:

I tried to log into an old youtube account, but didn't know the password.  Clicked on "forgot password" and end up being able to link the youtube account to my gmail account. This is good, and now I could post a video to youtube.

I later noticed that my account was listed as one of many google accounts on his computer, but didn't think much of it.  But just to put my mind at ease, I later changed the account's password, from MY computer.

Then I notice that he put two videos on my youtube account.  Perhaps he posted them before I had changed the password? But then later, they were gone?!  So he still has access to the account.

How can I keep him out of my account?  Changing the password didn't stop his access.  If he somehow linked my accounts to his, how do I find out, and how do I unlink them?  I really don't trust him to stay out of my email.

Answer (score 1):

You can [sign out of all devices](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154):

> Sign out from another computer If you forgot to sign out of your email on another computer, you can remotely sign out of Gmail.
>
> 1. Open Gmail.
> 2. In the bottom right corner, click Details >￼ Sign out all other web sessions.
>
> Tip: If you’re using a public or shared computer, sign out of your Google Account before leaving the computer.